# Phaser Js - How to flip Image after colliding with world bounds?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

In my game some dogs are randomly walking. Suppose they are moving from left to right, what I need is when it reaches the right boundary of the game world, then the dog animation should be flipped and vice versa. I know that flipping can be achieved when we give **`dog.scale.x = -1`**.
But I don't know when this should be applied, I have set **`dog.body.collideWorldBounds = true;`**.

Also now I am using **`myGame.physics.arcade.velocityFromRotation(dog.rotation, 100, dog.body.velocity);`** for moving the dog, let me know if any other options.

The js code can be see here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/rbfg0h9o/1/ and a working demo in this link: http://abhilashrs.com/game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a couple of options:

1) Monitor the dogs `velocity.x` and adjust the scale.x accordingly. So if the velocity changes from negative to positive, you flip the scale as required.

2) Collide with a hidden object instead of the world bounds. By doing this you can take advantage of collision callbacks and adjust the dog scale as required.

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1737823/photonstorm" >PhotonStorm</a> Did you see my code for moving the animation do we have any other better way than what I do.
myGame.physics.arcade.velocityFromRotation(dog.rotation, 100, dog.body.velocity);

Comment: It depends what you want to do. There's nothing wrong with using `velocityFromRotation`, it depends on your game. For certain types of game this will be fine.